# show a window every few seconds in home screen in Android

Tags: android

I`m new to android.

I want to write an alarm system in android.

I want to show a window (or dialog) every few seconds (or hours) in home screen and i want to hide it after a few second.

how can i do it?

Comment: Start by reading android documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing dialog every few seconds your needed create Service where you will create Timer with period. And for hide after a few second use Toast with duration.

Answer (score 1):

Use AlarmManager to trigger alarm and use BroadcastReceiver to handle the alarm notice then pop up dialog